# File import with few non-na cols in big table

Tags: r, csv, import

I would like to import a csv-file with about 10,000 columns. I have tried `fread` as well as `read.csv`, but neither function seems to do the job.

The problem is that the first column is totally empty, except for a random number on the top left (file number). Then in the first row after the file name, there are the column names following to the right end. Let's assume I have only 3 columns which contain both NAs and integers. The rest of the 9,997 columns are all empty (i.e. the column names do exist, but they do not contain any value, downwards).

I would like to fill those columns with NAs, but at the same time keep those 3 correcly filled columns intact. This does not seem to be possible? Reading in the data always kills every single row after the first one, even though I have 3 columns which last until the end row (let's say row 100). Thus I would expect the whole file to be imported until row 100.

What am I doing wrong?

Unfortunately I don't have a sample file for this problem but I tried to describe as clearly as possible.

edit: code for import by csv:

```
read.csv(csvfile, sep = ";", na.strings=c("NA","..",""," "), stringsAsFactors = F, 
              header = T, as.is = T, dec = ".",fill = TRUE,quote="")
```

code for fread:

```
fread(csvfile, sep = ";", na.strings=c("NA","..",""," "), stringsAsFactors = F, 
           header = T)
```

I believe the problem can also be described as unequal column length.

Comment: I would recommend first scrubbing this file using some other tool, e.g. Notepad++ if it can be opened, or something like Java.  Get it into a format which `read.csv` can handle.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok but what is the actual problem here? The missing row names? I mean it would be easy to calculate the max size as longest row times longest col, and fill the rest with NAs right?
edit: also I have a couple more files in that format and I am looking for an automated solution, if possible in any case.

Comment: The first line can either have headers, or the first line can be data.  This is as far as `read.csv` will take you.

Comment: Ok I understand, but my first row has 3 datapoints and 9997 NA values. Sorry to ask again, but I dont see what is the problem here yet.

Comment: `read.csv` has the skip argument which you could use to skip the headers. That would leave you with the data without column names, but maybe these can be added some other way, of only three columns are of interest. I don't know `fread` but hope, it will have something similar as skip.

Comment: @Bernhard ty for the comment, but I also need to keep the column names for later on. I have more files in that format, and sometimes are lot more columns are filled (luckily).

Comment: You might read the file twice: Once the header column with the argument `nrows` and then the data with the argument `skip`. After you have removed the first element of the header row, you should be able to set the column names to the columns.

Comment: I have just tested `skip`. Unfortunately it did not help. Now I have 0 rows and 10,000 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We apparently have a data file with one entry to much in the first line. Let's use the following string as an example:

```
example <- "filename;col_one;col_two;col_three
1;2;3
4;5;6
7;8;9
5;;
"
```

this will not work

```
read.table(text=example, sep=";", header=TRUE)
```

but this will read the headers

```
scan(text=example, what="character", nlines=1, sep=";")
```

and this will read the data

```
read.table(text=example, sep=";", header=FALSE, skip=1)
```

You will have to remove the filename from the headers and combine headers and data again. It is very unfortunate, that the last line will not translate to `fread`easily, as far as I can see.